# problems : button next/prev jumps two step in full calendar?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, ionic-framework, fullcalendar

I'm using the fullcalendar on my ionic project on iOS iPad and facing this issue, when tying to navigate (days, weeks and even months) the calendar jumps two steps forward.
For example I'm actually on "May" and when clicking next it'll jump over "June" and it will take me to July.

THANKS ;)

Comment: Can't help much without seeing any code, but a pretty common issue when working with iOS touch events is taps register multiple "clicks" e.g. the tap registers, then a click (touch events still send click events as well as touch events). I'd be worth checking if this is the case for you.

Comment: i use only example simple http://fullcalendar.io/blog/2016/03/touch-support/